# Virtualbox и исчезновение /boot/grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, grub

Есть Windows 7 + Virtualbox и установленный Ubuntu Desktop 14.
Эпизодически создаются снапшоты от Vbox. В Ubuntu постоянно происходят обновление системы, и в какой-то момент при следующей загрузке Ubuntu выдает ошибку 
`error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found`.
По-настоящему, папка /boot/ пустая вообще.

Я пытаюсь переключиться на предыдущий снапшот, но ошибка та же, и даже самый первый образ тоже сломанный. То есть бэкапы я зря делал. За год такое уже повторилось 3 раза.

1. Почему могли исчезнуть данные из `/boot/` ?
2. Почему сломаны все раннее сделанные снапшоты и оригинал?
3. Как можно это исправить, не начиная все с нуля?

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=51714 - я так понимаю, если повредить начальный образ, то всё поломается.

Comment: как можно повредить начальный образ, если только последний слой доступный для записи, с виртуалки

Comment: *как можно повредить начальный образ* — если он хранится в отдельном файле, то его (файл), можно, например, удалить.

Comment: @duhon, с виртуалки - да, а из основной системы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, 2. похоже, что в каталог `/boot` у вас монтировался раздел, находящийся на другом виртуальном (или реальном) блочном устройстве (т.н. диске).

3. наиболее простой путь: найти «пропавший» раздел.

более сложный:

- загрузить эту виртуальную машину с какого-нибудь другого образа (подойдёт практически любой установочный/live/«спасательный»/и т.п. от любого дистрибутива *gnu/linux*), подлкючив его как дополнительное блочное устройство
- примонтировать все необходимые разделы, начиная с корневого, в каталог (к примеру) `/mnt`
- скачать и скопировать в `/mnt` файл с пакетом с подходящей версией *linux-а*
- сделать `chroot /mnt`
- там, в *chroot-е*, установить пакет с *linux-ом*: `dpkg -i файл`
- на всякий случай (по идее эта команда должна выполниться в процессе установки пакета с *linux-ом*) выполнить ещё и `update-grub`
- выйти из *chroot-а*
- отмонтировать то, что монтировали, перезагрузить виртуальную машину без вспомогательного образа

Comment: /boot не монтировался с других блочных устройств, так как это рабочая виртуалка, там самый простой вариант 20гб на одном диске кроме своп

Comment: А если без `chroot` с помощью `grub-install` (если он входит в спасательную ОС) установить GRUB, то он разве испортит предыдущую установку?

Comment: @approximatenumber, у автора вопроса каталог `/boot` пуст. для загрузки там должны быть не только файлы *grub*-а, но и хоть какая-нибудь программа *linux*.